# What is wrong in the format of this find command in a Makefile?

Tags: windows, shell, sed, cmd, makefile

The Makefile from [this](https://github.com/earlephilhower/mklittlefs.git) github repo is giving me trouble and I have no experience in Make file syntax and really need your help :)

First error is on line 61 and is related to the format of the 'find' command. The command is this:

```
FILES_TO_FORMAT := $(shell find . -not -path './littlefs/*' \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' \))
```

The error is this:

"FIND: Parameter format not correct"

Second error is on line 66:

```
# clang doesn't seem to handle -D "ARG=\"foo bar\"" correctly, so replace spaces with \x20:
BUILD_CONFIG_STR := $(shell echo $(CPPFLAGS) | sed 's- -\\\\x20-g')
```

Error says:

'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: This makefile is meant to run on a POSIX system like GNU/Linux or MacOS.  You are, apparently, trying to run it on a Windows system.  That won't work.

Comment: From the documentation, under `Build` : *On Windows, use MinGW* "find" on Windows locates a string in a file. In *nix, it locates a file. `Mingw` overrides the Windows version with the *nix version.  `sed` is a commonly-found third-party utility. Google is your friend.

Comment: options: 1. run this in Windows Subsystem for Linux.  2. try using Cygwin or Git-Bash as your shell.  3. try re-writing the commands in PowerShell